# comment code in netbeans?

Tags: php, netbeans, phpdoc

a while ago i could comment any code in php with netbeans like this:

```
/*
 *
 *
 */
```

I just typed /* ENTER and netbeans gave me that lines above. then when i typed @ it gave me a full list of all available tags (author, param and so on).

i reinstalled my mac and since then it hasnt worked.

someone knows why and how i can activate it? i installed the netbeans for php only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you import from an old user profile by any chance? This happened to me once. I reset the preferences and it worked. Hope this helps.

**Edit**: The OP reported that you have to press /** ENTER rather than /* ENTER to get the comments working.

Comment: how do i purge all old user profile? (and how do i reinstall/uninstall netbeans in mac. there is no such file in /Applications/Netbeans)

Comment: You can try this. Go to Tools -> Options. Under Keymap, set the profile as eclipse once and try if it works. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Check this - http://www.mybelovedphp.com/2009/01/27/netbeans-revisited-code-completion-for-code-igniter-ii/#comment-46501 . May be you changed your project structure?

Comment: thanks it worked.. i was just typing /* ENTER. you have to type /** ENTER :) could you add this to your answer? i marked it as the right one.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest 1 of the following:

```
1) Completely uninstall netbeans and install again
```

or

```
2) Check Tools->Options->Editor->Code Templates
   You may also want to check the settings in 
   Check Tools->Options->Editor->Code Completion
```

Comment: have checked everything. i press @ within the comment block but still no list of all available tags. i should show up immediately without me having to press ENTER or TAB

Comment: Complete removal is not necessary since a new version always installs itself into a separate location and keeps all its own settings.